# openvpn клиент на ubuntu не подключается к серверу

Tags: linux, openvpn

При запуске openvpn на клиенте ошибок не появляется, но адаптера tun0 в ip addr нет и ping 10.8.0.1 не проходит.

Клиент запускаю командой openvpn --config client.ovpn
пишет:

```
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 OpenVPN 2.4.7 x86_64-pc-linux-gnu [SSL (OpenSSL)] [LZO] [LZ4] [EPOLL] [PKCS11] [MH/PKTINFO] [AEAD] built on Jul 19 2021
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 library versions: OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020, LZO 2.10
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 Outgoing Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Cipher 'AES-256-CTR' initialized with 256 bit key
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 Incoming Control Channel Encryption: Using 256 bit message hash 'SHA256' for HMAC authentication
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]{ip}:3478
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 Socket Buffers: R=[212992->212992] S=[212992->212992]
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 UDP link local: (not bound)
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 UDP link remote: [AF_INET]{ip}:3478
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]{ip}:3478, sid=431b85e5 c1be5ddd
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 VERIFY OK: depth=1, CN=ChangeMe
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 VERIFY KU OK
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 Validating certificate extended key usage
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 ++ Certificate has EKU (str) TLS Web Server Authentication, expects TLS Web Server Authentication
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 VERIFY EKU OK
Fri Dec 24 10:38:29 2021 VERIFY OK: depth=0, CN=server
```

client.ovpn

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote {ip} 3478
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 3
{ca, cert, key, tls-crypt}
```

Как подключить клиента на ubuntu server 20 к openvpn?

server logs:

```
{ip}:1150 TLS: Initial packet from [AF_INET]{ip}:1150, sid=a2251623 3caed097
{ip}:1150 VERIFY ERROR: depth=0, error=unsupported certificate purpose: CN=server
{ip}:1150 OpenSSL: error:1417C086:SSL routines:tls_process_client_certificate:certificate verify failed
{ip}:1150 TLS_ERROR: BIO read tls_read_plaintext error
{ip}:1150 TLS Error: TLS object -> incoming plaintext read error
{ip}:1150 TLS Error: TLS handshake failed
{ip}:1150 SIGUSR1[soft,tls-error] received, client-instance restarting
```

Comment: а на сервере в логах что-то интересное есть?

Comment: @Fat-Zer добавил логи, так почему-то ошибка, хотя если подключаюсь через ui клиент на другой машине, то все работает

Comment: точно не подсовываешь вместо клиентского ключа серверный? как именно клиентский ключ генерировал/подписывал? что говорит о назначении сертификате `openssl x509 -in client.crt -text -noout -purpose`?

Comment: @Fat-Zer все ключи находятся в файле конфигурации клиента, сгенерированы с помощью скрипта https://github.com/Nyr/openvpn-install

Comment: @Fat-Zer , точно, была ошибка с файлом конфигурации, сгенерировал новый, все заработало. Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: ок... хорошо...